# cypress conditional code logic depending on existence of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, cypress, exists

I want to perfomr some action depending on the existence of an element. Something like:

```
cy.get(A).should('not.exist').then(()=>{ //action 1 })
cy.get(A).should('exist').then(()=>{ //action 2 })
```

And I need to perform both checks.

Problem is I am using "should" assertion to perform this check. If the element exists then the entire test case fails and I don't even reach to second check for performing action 2.

Is there anything like a soft assert in cypress which lets me just check if element exists or not and does not fails the test case if it doesn't ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the documentation at [Element existence](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Element-existence)

> You cannot do conditional testing on the DOM unless you are either:
>
> - Server side rendering with no asynchronous JavaScript.
> - Using client side JavaScript that only ever does synchronous rendering.
>
> It is crucial that you understand how your application works else you will write flaky tests.

If the above is true, you can substitute a jQuery expression

```
const exists = Cypress.$.('A').length > 0;
if (exists) { 
  //action 1 
} else {
  //action 2 
}
```

But if 'A' is asynchronously loaded, the above will fail.

One way is to check another element 'B' that is asynchronously loaded along with 'A'

```
cy.get('B')      // 'B' is definitely loaded
  .then(() => {
    // since 'B' is present, we can test for 'A'
    const exists = Cypress.$.('A').length > 0;
    if (exists) { 
      //action 1 
    } else {
      //action 2 
    }
  })
```